# Simplify python plot with legend into loop

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, for-loop, simplify

Any ideas to simplify the following code into a loop in a good way? The repeating code is going to thousands. e.g. test-101.csv...test-2233.csv

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


data = pd.read_csv('reports/test-101.csv', header=None)
line1, = plt.plot(data[2], data[1], label='line 101')
line1m, = plt.plot(np.array([0, 12]), np.array([np.mean(data[1]), 
np.mean(data[1])]), label='line-101 mean')

data = pd.read_csv('reports/test-102.csv', header=None)
line2, = plt.plot(data[2], data[1], label='line 102')
line2m, = plt.plot(np.array([0, 12]), np.array([np.mean(data[1]), 
np.mean(data[1])]), label='line-102 mean')

data = pd.read_csv('reports/test-103.csv', header=None)
line3, = plt.plot(data[2], data[1], label='line 103')
line3m, = plt.plot(np.array([0, 12]), np.array([np.mean(data[1]), 
np.mean(data[1])]), label='line-103 mean')
.
.
.


plt.legend(handles=[line1, line2, line3,
                      line1m, line2m, line3m])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this might help

```
import os

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

csv_dir = 'reports/'
csv_files = [csv for csv in os.listdir(csv_dir)]

plt_handles = []
index = 0

for csv_file in csv_files:
    # You can parse the csv_file to get the index handle if you wish
    data = pd.read_csv(csv_dir + csv_file, header=None)
    line, = plt.plot(data[2], data[1], label='line %d' % index)
    line_m, = plt.plot(np.array([0, 12]), np.array([np.mean(data[1]), 
        np.mean(data[1])]), label='line-%d mean' % index)

    plt_handles.append((line, line_m))
    index += 1  # for demonstration purposes - if you do not parse csv fname

lines, lines_m = zip(*plt_handles)  # transpose matrix - lines before means

plt.legend(handles=lines + lines_m)
```

Comment: How to loop the label as well?

Comment: I improved the answer, forgot about the label

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to simplify this line (`line_m, = ...`) as well?

Comment: Glad I could help. I haven't got the data you have, neither I know what you exactly wanna do with them, but I think you can simplify the second argument with `np.full((2,), data[1].mean())`. I am sure there are many ways to simplify things in python. Just play with it.

Comment: Thanks. That's all I need. By the way you need to fix `dirname` in your code.